# XSLT Parameter not working

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation

I am using a XSLT Transformer in Java.  I am sure the problem is in the way I'm typing in the XSLT syntax.

Basically, I have to see if an attribute 'id' in one of the nodes of XML is equivalent to a value, the XSL should process a template.  I need to pass this test value as a xsl:param.  When I test it on a static value, it works cool:

```
<ul class="levelOneNav">
 <xsl:for-each select="level1[@id='sub-page-1']">
  <xsl:call-template name="level1"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

The testing portion is in second line above.  AFAIK to put in a param inside the strings, the format is `<xsl:for-each select="level1[@id='$ContentID']">` in which `$ContentID` is the xsl:param declared as `<xsl:param name="ContentID"/>`

So this is the code I'm keying in

```
<ul class="levelOneNav">
 <xsl:for-each select="level1[@id='$ContentID']">
  <xsl:call-template name="level1"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

but it doesn't work.  I've also tried using `<xsl:for-each select="level1[@id='{$ContentID}']">`
and it also fails.

Any advise is appreciated greatly.  Please give me links if you feel I should learn something.  Thanks for your time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that “AFAIK” is where you are wrong. Some string values in *XSLT attributes* certainly do accept a `"{$param}"` syntax (note the braces), but in your case what you are after is much simpler: `@id=$ContentID`

EDIT: Note that the '{$param}' applies for *XSLT attributes*, see example:

```
<xsl:element name="{$namespace}:{$elementName}">
   <xsl:attribute name="{$attrName}"><xsl:value-of select="$value"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: thank you
I tried doing `<xsl:for-each select="level1[@id=$ContentID]">`
and `<xsl:for-each select="level1[@id='{$ContentID}']">`

after getting your answer, but they didn't work.  If i'm doing it wrong still, can you please advise me with a correct code snippet? thanks

Comment: Thanks.  Weblogic was somehow not rebuilding the .class files from cache and hence creating problems, this has worked after I deleted the classes and redeployed+restarted

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<ul class="levelOneNav">
<xsl:variable name="contentID" select="'sub-page-1'" />
 <xsl:for-each select="level1[@id=$ContentID]">
  <xsl:call-template name="level1"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

variable or param will work same way.
becareful you must remove simple quote around `$ContentID`.
another things if `level1/@id` is unique you don't need the foreach.

below an exemple to send the variable as param.

```
<ul class="levelOneNav">
    <xsl:variable name="contentID" select="'sub-page-1'" />
     <xsl:for-each select="level1[@id=$ContentID]">
      <xsl:call-template name="level1" >
           <xsl:with-param name="foo" select="$ContenID" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
     <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you for replying.  This would work if I can anyhow pass a xsl:param in place of 'sub-page-1' in second line of your snippet.

I tried `'{$ContentID}'` and `{$ContentID}` and also simply `$ContentID`

but none of them worked

Comment: thank you.  The other answer worked. WebLogic was somehow not re-creating the class file from jsp even after I restart and that's why changed values were not reflecting